# Handling Cookies containing equals ("=") sign in Java

Tags: java, cookies, httpclient

I am sending request in the following way.

```
    HttpClient httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();
    CookieStore cookieStore=new BasicCookieStore();
    HttpContext httpContext=new BasicHttpContext();
    httpContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
    httpClient.execute(httppost,httpContext);
```

My auth cookie on java side reads like this.

XNlciI6WzU2Mjk0OTk1MzQyMTMxMjAsMCwidEFlbVlLYlpuRXYyc29TNjBSOHhueCIsMTM3MzM0NzcyMCwxMzczMzQ3NzIwXX0\075|1373347720|5c1ad3ac3828516aa7178f00b3bba961fa29ae9b

(notice \075)

On server side it is like this.

XNlciI6WzU2Mjk0OTk1MzQyMTMxMjAsMCwiejJYUXpQQVhBQ0lQVkdCQU5FMkRtdSIsMTM3MzM0OTIyNiwxMzczMzQ5MjI2XX0

When I use python requests the cookie shown is as follows.

XNlciI6WzU2Mjk0OTk1MzQyMTMxMjAsMCwiclYzYW1FakRHc0dhampDcnhoMlBIVyIsMTM3MzM0OTEzNiwxMzczMzQ5MTM2XX0=|1373349137|e8900c8bfd2972ca4115ef1946b4cdf161a4815a

It appears that HttpClient is ignoring the bit after | (date code and stuff). Am I missing something?
I tried all the cookie policies as well, nothing working.

Comment: Have you noticed \075 is the ascii for equals(=)? Maybe the backslash is causing this to happen but I'm not exactly sure how your solution works.

Comment: Yes \075 is octal for (=). Are we supposed to treat (=) specially in cookies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I solved it in following way. Before I answer a few facts.

1. Cookies key-value pair are separated by "=".
2. Cookies that have "=" inside them must be escaped (the "=" part).
3. Cookies that include "=" need to be specified as Version1 cookies
4. Such cookies must be enclosed in double quotes.

This is my entire post method.

```
    public String doUrlPost(final String connurl,final JSONObject obj) throws IOException{
              CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
      CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);

      URL url=new URL(connurl);
       HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
         urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
         urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
         urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
                 //sets the cookie to version 1
         urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Cookie2","$Version=1");

         List<HttpCookie> lst=((CookieManager)CookieHandler.getDefault()).getCookieStore().getCookies();
         for(HttpCookie cookie:lst){

             if(cookie.getName().equals("auth")){
             //double quote your cookie
              urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Cookie","auth=\""+cookie.getValue()+"\"");
             }
         }
         urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);      

         List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = getData(obj);

         OutputStream out = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
         BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8"));           
         writer.write(getQuery(nameValuePairs));
         writer.close();

        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader rd=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String line="";
        String content="";
        while((line=rd.readLine())!=null){
            content+=line;
        }
        rd.close();
        finalcontent=content;
        urlConnection.disconnect(); 
        return finalcontent;
}
```

Get query method

```
    private String getQuery(List<NameValuePair> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;

    for (NameValuePair pair : params)
    {
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getName(), "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and solved it by writing my own Cookie-Parser method:

```
/**
 * Modified method to parse cookies which contain "=" in their value.<br>
 * The default method {@link HttpServletRequest#getCookies()} cuts off cookies values at the first occurrence of "=".
 * 
 * @param httpRequest
 * @return
 */
public static Map<String, Cookie> parseCookies(HttpServletRequest httpRequest)
{
    return parseCookies(httpRequest.getHeader("Cookie"));
}

public static Map<String, Cookie> parseCookies(String cookieHeader)
{
    Map<String, Cookie> result = new LinkedHashMap<String, Cookie>();
    if (cookieHeader != null)
    {
        String[] cookiesRaw = cookieHeader.split("; ");
        for (int i = 0; i < cookiesRaw.length; i++)
        {
            String[] parts = cookiesRaw[i].split("=", 2);
            String value = parts.length > 1 ? parts[1] : "";
            if (value.length() >= 2 && value.startsWith("\"") && value.endsWith("\""))
            {
                value = value.substring(1, value.length() - 1);
            }
            result.put(parts[0], new Cookie(parts[0], value));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use Jetty's [CookieCutter](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.x/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/CookieCutter.java) instead of writing my own parser.